# Conditionally initialize new list

Tags: c#, list, model, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I'm reading an excel file into a model.
The model contains data for up to 4 rows of excel data, the first three columns of the row would be the "header" of the model, the rest of the data would be details.
if the cell in column 4 contains an * the data on that row should append that row to the preceding row.

Question:  How do read in the row or rows if there is an * in the cell 4 of the row conditionally?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

```
for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++) //1
{

    if (row < 4700)
    {

        sourceStock.Row = row;

        if (workSheet.Cells[row, 4].Value != null)
        {
            if (workSheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString().ToFixedString(50).Contains("*"))
            {

                appendLine = true;
                appendedRow++;

            }
            else
            {
                sourceStock.CabName = workSheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString().ToFixedString(50);

                appendLine = false;
                appendedRow = 0;
            }
        }

        if (!appendLine)
        {
            sourceStock.RowAppend = 0;
            CLRow0(workSheet, sourceStock, row);
            //    sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
        }
        else
        {
            if (appendedRow == 1)
            {
                CLRow1(workSheet, sourceStock, row);
                if (workSheet.Cells[row + 1, 4].Value != null)
                {
                    if (!workSheet.Cells[row + 1, 4].Value.ToString().Contains("*"))
                    {
                        sourceStock.RowAppend = 1;
                        //          sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                        appendedRow = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sourceStock.RowAppend = 1;
                    //       sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                    appendedRow = 0;
                }
            }

            if (appendedRow == 2)
            {
                CLRow2(workSheet, sourceStock, row);
                if (workSheet.Cells[row + 1, 4].Value != null)
                {
                    if (!workSheet.Cells[row + 1, 4].Value.ToString().Contains("*"))
                    {
                        sourceStock.RowAppend = 2;
                        //        sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                        appendedRow = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sourceStock.RowAppend = 2;
                    //     sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                    appendedRow = 0;
                }
            }

            if (appendedRow == 3)
            {
                CLRow3(workSheet, sourceStock, row);
                if (workSheet.Cells[row + 1, 4].Value != null)
                {
                    if (!workSheet.Cells[row + 1, 4].Value.ToString().Contains("*"))
                    {
                        sourceStock.RowAppend = 3;
                        //     sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                        appendedRow = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sourceStock.RowAppend = 3;
                    //    sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                    appendedRow = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you isolate exactly what you are having trouble with?  Dumping poorly formatted code and asking what do I do, doesn't make a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a while statement to append the rows as needed.  Seems to be working.

```
                        {

                            if (row < 4700) //4700)
                            {
                                // TODO   how to start a  new sourceStock 
                                // using append row

                                sourceStock = new SourceStockCLModelPM();

                                if (i == 2)
                                {
                                    sourceStock.IsClassic = true;
                                    sourceStock.IsDeluxe = false;
                                    sourceStock.IsGL = false;
                                }

                                if (i == 3)
                                {
                                    sourceStock.IsClassic = false;
                                    sourceStock.IsDeluxe = true;
                                    sourceStock.IsGL = false;
                                }
                                if (i == 4)
                                {
                                    sourceStock.IsClassic = false;
                                    sourceStock.IsDeluxe = false;
                                    sourceStock.IsGL = true;
                                }
                                Console.WriteLine("Row = " + row);
                                sourceStock.Row = row;

                                if (workSheet.Cells[row, 4].Value != null)
                                {
                                    int whileRow = 0;
                                      sourceStock.CabName = workSheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString().ToFixedString(50);
                                    if (workSheet.Cells[row + 1, 4].Value != null)
                                    {


                                        while (workSheet.Cells[row + 1, 4].Value.ToString().Contains("*"))
                                        {
                                            row++;
                                            readInXrows++;



                                            //if (workSheet.Cells[row + 1, 2].Value == null)
                                            //{
                                            //    break;
                                            //}
                                        }

                                        if (readInXrows == 0)
                                        {
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 0);
                                            CLRow0(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);


                                        }

                                        if (readInXrows == 1)
                                        {
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 0);
                                            CLRow0(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 1);
                                            CLRow1(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);


                                            sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                                        }
                                        if (readInXrows == 2)
                                        {
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 0);
                                            CLRow0(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 1);
                                            CLRow1(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 2);
                                            CLRow2(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);


                                            sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                                        }
                                        if (readInXrows == 3)
                                        {
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 0);
                                            CLRow0(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 1);
                                            CLRow1(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 2);
                                            CLRow2(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 3);
                                            CLRow3(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);



                                            sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                                        }
                                        if (readInXrows == 4)
                                        {
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 0);
                                            CLRow0(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 1);
                                            CLRow1(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 2);
                                            CLRow2(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 3);
                                            CLRow3(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);

                                            sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                                        }
                                        if (readInXrows == 5)
                                        {
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 0);
                                            CLRow0(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 1);
                                            CLRow1(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 2);
                                            CLRow2(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);
                                            whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 3);
                                            CLRow3(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);

                                            sourceCNCList.Add(sourceStock);
                                        }

                                       
                                    }else
                                    {
                                        whileRow = row - (readInXrows - 0);
                                        CLRow0(workSheet, sourceStock, whileRow);

                                    }
                                }

                              
                            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).